# Connect to SQL Server named instance by ip

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming that i have a server named PROD-DB.

This server has configured 2 ip: 192.168.100.5, 192.168.100.6

On PROD-DB are running 2 SQL Server instances: SQLINSTANCE1, SQLINSTANCE2.

Is there any possibility to connect to SQL Servers on this server without specifying the named instance, filtering by ip?

Example: 
If some application tries to connect to PROD-DB having configured Server=192.168.100.5, then somehow connect to instance PROD-DB\SQLINSTANCE1

If another application tries to connect to PROD-DB having configured Server=192.168.100.6, then somehow connect to instance PROD-DB\SQLINSTANCE2

Comment: this looks promising: "Hostname Alias SQL Server instance" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/05/21/how-to-add-a-hostname-alias-for-a-sql-server-instance/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to connect via the IP and Port configured for that instance. In SQL Server Configuration manager, expand the SQL Server Network Configuration tab, select the relevant instance name, and take a look at the TCP port number configured for that instance. I think that the TCP/IP protocol will need to be set to "enabled". Then to connect to the server via IP and port use the "192.168.100.5,YOUR_PORT_NUMBER" as the "server name" in your connection string

Comment: But without specifying port number in app config? I just want to append these ip to the new server and do not change app config

Comment: Perhaps this article might help? http://serverfault.com/questions/272620/can-you-have-two-sql-instances-on-1-server-with-an-ip-each-for-local-network-ac
or you could try the option provided by "devio" in the comment on your question